# Incrementing Integers in Map

Tags: java, integer, hash-map

I have a `HashMap<Token, Integer>`, which counts occurrences of `Token`. Each time `Token` is found, the value in the map should be incremented.

```
Map<Token, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<Token, Integer>();
// ...

public void tokenFound(Token token) {

    Integer numberOfOccurs = occurrences.get(token);
    Integer newNumberOfOccurs = new Integer((numberOfOccurs == null) ? 1 : numberOfOccurs.intValue() + 1);
    occurrences.put(token, newNumberOfOccurs);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: [Functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor)... if your weren't `Java` bound...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have several different options for this:

#### Guava

Google's Guava Library introduces the idea of a [Multiset](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) which is capable of counting the occurrences, and also provides a couple of other features.

#### Java 8

If you are using Java 8 (which I highly recommend if you have the ability to do so), your `tokenFound` method can simply be this:

```
occurrences.merge(token, 1, (oldValue, one) -> oldValue + one);
```

Or this:

```
occurrences.compute(token, (tokenKey, oldValue) -> oldValue == null ? 1 : oldValue + 1);
```

Note that as of Java 7, you can initialize the map with the "diamond operator":

```
Map<Token, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();
```

#### Without Java 8, no libraries

If you are unable to use Java 8 and don't want to add Guava as a third party library to your project, there are a small part you can do to simplify your existing code:

```
Integer previousValue = occurrences.get(token);
occurrences.put(token, previousValue == null ? 1 : previousValue + 1);
```

More specifically:

- Using the `new Integer` constructor is not necessary, Java automatically uses *boxing* to do this. For Integer values close to zero, this will actually save you a little bit because Java keeps some integers cached.
- You don't need the `newNumberOfOccurs` variable as it's only used once.

Comment: To supplement the integer caching part: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29 (-128 to 127)

Comment: Awesome! p.s. I found out that you can slightly simplify the first example to:

`occurrences.merge(token, 1, Integer::sum);` 


(Integer::sum is just a BiFunction that adds two integers)

Answer (score 10):

Guava's [`Multiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) and its [`AtomicLongMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html) are designed for this kind of counting.

See also:

- [Guava's new collection types, explained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained).
- *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries* (The author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.)

Answer (score 6):

I feel the non library answers can be improved, so here's my take at those.

For java 7 :

```
private final Map<Token, AtomicInteger> occurrences = new HashMap<>();

public void tokenFound(Token token) {
    if (!occurrences.containsKey(token)) {
        occurrences.put(token, new AtomicInteger(1));
        return;
    }
    occurrences.get(token).incrementAndGet();
}
```

You use `AtomicInteger` as value type, allowing an easy `incrementAndGet()`, instead of having to overwrite the bucket in the `Map`.

For Java 8 :

```
private final Map<Token, LongAdder> occurrences = new HashMap<>();

public void tokenFound(Token token) {
    occurrences.computeIfAbsent(token, (t) -> new LongAdder()).increment();
}
```

`LongAdder` is a type specifically made for tallying (especially under heavy concurrency). The added `computeIfAbsent()` method on `Map` and the addition of lambdas turn this whole thing into a one-liner.

If you're using java 7, I'd opt for Guava, but if you're on 8 simply use the `java.util` classes.

Comment: I would beg you *not* to use `AtomicInteger` for this, but only to use it if you're actually running in a concurrent context. If I had to maintain this code and found out that `AtomicInteger` was being used to avoid a single extra line of code, I'd be pretty annoyed for the time I spent trying to figure out how this class was used concurrently.

Comment: @ChrisHayes you can also simply roll your own wrapper around an `int` with an `increment()` method. The 'elegance' from my solution does not come from using `AtomicInteger` per se, but from using a mutable value type in the map. If you do use `AtomicInteger`, you can annotate the class with the JCIP annotation `@NotThreadSafe` to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think I'd be *more* confused if I saw a class which went out of the way to use thread-safe types within itself and was annotated as not thread safe. ;) I like the elegance of simply being able to call `increment`, to be sure.

Comment: LongAdder?! One never stops learning. Your pure java8 example really neat. I wish, I could upvote 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `Map<Token, Integer>`, use `Map<Token, int[]>`.

This can be used to avoid calling `put()` whenever you want to
modify an existing value.

```
HashMap<String, int[]> m=new HashMap<>();
m.put("a", new int[]{0});
m.get("a")[0]++;
System.out.println("m="+m.get("a")[0]);
```

Outputs:

```
m=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8:

Although the `merge` and `compute` methods in `Map` work for this purpose, the `Map.getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)` show the intention of the code more clearly to me.

```
Map<Token, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<Token, Integer>();

// for each token:
occurrences.put(token, occurrences.getOrDefault(token, 0) + 1);
```